# Как добавить читаемый плеерами кодек при захвате видео через ffmpeg? Linux

Tags: html, linux, видео, ffmpeg, online-video

пытаюсь решить проблему с воспроизведением файла в который пишет ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://11.7.197.23:554/ISAPI/Streaming/Channels/103 -c copy -map 0:0 /video/video6.mp4
```

Извлекаю записанный файл и не могу ничем воспроизвести кроме vlc плеера. А файл нужно воспроизводить в web плеерах, те тем более его не потянут. Подскажите может какой кодек добавить чтобы сразу в нем сразу записывался файл или какой веб плеер который сможет воспроизвести видео с таким описанием?

**Инфа о файле: video6.mp4**

```html
General
Complete name               : C:\Users\pivovarov_ev\Desktop\config\video6.mp4
Format                      : MPEG-4
Format profile              : Base Media
Codec ID                    : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
File size                   : 46.9 MiB
Duration                    : 28 s 0 ms
Overall bit rate mode       : Constant
Overall bit rate            : 14.0 Mb/s
Movie name                  : Media Presentation
Writing application         : Lavf57.56.101

Video
ID                          : 1
Format                      : JPEG
Codec ID                    : 6C
Duration                    : 28 s 0 ms
Bit rate mode               : Constant
Bit rate                    : 14.0 Mb/s
Width                       : 1 280 pixels
Height                      : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio        : 16:9
Frame rate mode             : Variable
Frame rate                  : 17.393 FPS
Minimum frame rate          : 12.500 FPS
Maximum frame rate          : 25.000 FPS
Color space                 : YUV
Chroma subsampling          : 4:2:0
Bit depth                   : 8 bits
Compression mode            : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)          : 0.876
Stream size                 : 46.9 MiB (100%)
```

Comment: Если у вас видео JPEG, то контейнер mkv или avi делайте

Comment: Если же хочется перекодировать во что-то нормальное и чтоб в браузерах хорошо показывало, то однозначно h264

Comment: jpeg можно проиграть через тег img

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, вам нужен [VP8/VP9](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libvpx). Или [webp](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libwebp). В любом случае, по ссылкам список кодеков, почитайте.

Answer (score 2):

H.264 видео в MP4-контейнере — достаточно стандартный вариант для всех и всяких вебплееров. Но не для живого стриминга, учтите.

Answer (score 1):

Совместимость кодеков смотрите в таблице к примеру

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility

h264 вроде норм, возможно Вы сможете переключить Вашу камеру на аппаратное кодирование в него.

Контейнер `HLS`  или `segment` лучше всего подходят для записи потоков. Тут не надо самому нарезать видео файлам. FFMPEG сделает всё сам - вам только отдать папку с файлами и плэйлист в веб-сервер.